# download part of video up to certain resolution

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

This command will download part of the video

```
youtube-dl -g "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFlrc16xjik" | awk '{ if(NR==1) print $0 }' | sed "s/^/'/;s/$/'/" | xargs -I {} ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v copy -ss 0 -t 10 probe.mp4
```

is there a way to limit the resolution (let's say 480)?

by default It picks the best quality, in this case 1080

Comment: `man youtube-dl -> -f` `-f 134` is probably what you're looking for

Comment: oh thanks, I've missed that.